# Can "auf" mean "during" like "bei"?

Tags: preposition

This is, for me, unverifiable information; hence this question.

Someone with a deeper knowledge of German than mine has recently told me that *auf* can also mean *during*, just like *bei*.

For instance, this person has told me that *bei Tage(e)* or *bei Nacht* can equally be rephrased as *auf Tag(e)* and *auf Nacht*, without losing its meaning.

However, my own research has turned no proof that this might be true.

Is it true?

Comment: South-German dialects: *Auf d'Nacht trink i immer an Wein, dann kann i besser schlafn.* Actually means **before** the night.

Answer (score 2):

One thing I can imagine is that you mean something like:

> in der **Nacht** von Montag **auf** Dienstag / in der **Nacht auf** Dienstag

This indeed means *»during the night from monday to tuesday«*.

*»Auf Tag/Nacht«* cannot mean *»bei Tag/Nacht«*, but can at least be used to describe a day/night partly:

> Die Übergangsphase von Nacht **auf Tag** heißt Morgendämmerung.
>   *(The transitional phase from night to day is called dawn.)*
>
> Die Übergangsphase von Tag **auf Nacht** heißt Abenddämmerung.
>   *(The transitional phase from night to day is called dusk.)*

However, *»auf«* can mean *»during«*.

> Auf der Reise gab es viel zu sehen.
>   *(There was a lot to see during the journey.)*

Comment: And can _Auf der Reise gab es viel zu sehen_ be rephrased as _Bei der Reise gab es viel zu sehen_?

Comment: Rule of thumb: you say *Ich gehe **auf** eine Reise.* Not *zu*. It's better to use *auf* in all occassions in that case. For those you can go both *auf* and *zu*, both *auf* and *bei* are okay. For those you can only go *zu* not *auf*, it's always *bei*.

Comment: @user26328:  This would be unusual or even wrong. _»Beim Reisen gab es viel zu sehen«_ is an alternative (second choice). Better: _»Während der Reise ...«_

Comment: "Auf" in a timely sense usually discribes a transition. That can be from one day to another, from one place to another or past something. The specific points are not always necessary to include but you rather put an emphasis on what kind of transition it is.

Answer (score 0):

Again, upon further study, I have discovered that *auf* and *bei* can both mean *during* (*während*), according to [a most authoritative source](http://www.duden.de/woerterbuch/deutsch-englisch/auf).

Also, by all accounts, they do seem to be interchangeable when meaning *during* (*während*), at least according to [this source](https://www.korrekturen.de/forum.pl/md/read/id/102698/sbj/auf-bei-einem-spaziergang/), of which reputability I have for the time being absolutely no clue at all (except, perhaps, its being a German language learning site).

In conclusion, then, as far as these credible sources are concerned, and very much at variance with what [Pollitzer](https://german.stackexchange.com/users/20967/pollitzer) told me earlier in the day, the generic »*Während* der Reise...« does seem in sooth to be fairly interchangeable with both »*Bei* der Reise...« and »Auf der Reise...«.

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question. *Auf Nacht is in nowhere near in meaning to "bei nacht". In fact, I'd call it entirely meaningless.